# Find proper sequence of scalars for a sequence converging to zero

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a normed vector space and $(x_n)$ be a sequence of $X$ that converges to zero.

Can I always find a sequence of scalars $(\lambda_n)$ such that 
$\lambda_n\rightarrow\infty$ and $\lambda_n x_n\rightarrow0$?

Comment: If the $x_n$ are non zero, you can use $\lambda_n=1/\sqrt{x_n}$.

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you could just take
$$
\lambda_n = \begin{cases}
1/\sqrt{\|x_n\|} & x_n\neq 0\\
n & x_n = 0
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Oh, I should have thought more about that.-///- Thanks.